# How to solve a BVP with known parameters?

Tags: scipy, differential-equations

I need to solve a boundary value problem (BVP) of second order, where the equation depends on several know parameters, which are geometric parameters and material constants.

I would like to solve this equation for several combinations of values of the known parameters. Is it possible to do this using `solve_bvp()`? I am thinking along the lines of the `args` parameter in `solve_ivp()`.

In case my question is unclear, imagine I want to solve the Bratu equation from the [solve_bvp() documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html) for several values of `k`, without having to each time change the value of `k` in the function `fun(x,y)`. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: The documentation says you can write a function of the form `f(x,y,p)` where `p` will be an array of additional parameters. So you could just pass `k` in as an element of `p`.

Comment: Thanks @Tyberius for your comment but the documentation says "p is a k-D vector of *unknown* parameters ". In my case, the parameters are known

Comment: Sorry, I had glossed over that in the docs. I think I may have found an alternative solution that I added as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `solve_ivp` also didn't have `args` until fairly recently, see the [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8352) on GitHub.

The workaround they suggest there is to use a lambda expression around your function, which will have the other arguments set as keywords.

For the Bratu equation, reworking the example from the documentation, I believe this would look like:

```
def fun(x, y,k=0):
    return np.vstack((y[1], -k*np.exp(y[0])))

def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0], yb[0]])

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
y_a = np.zeros((2, x.size))

res_a = solve_bvp(lambda x,y: fun(x,y,k=1), bc, x, y_a)
```

Comment: why do you define k=0 in the definition of fun?

Comment: @RonShvartsman this was just to make clear that `k` is a keyword argument, rather than a positional one. I could also have written `def fun(x,y,*,k)` to make it a keyword without setting a default value.